# Magento 2 Make "View and Edit Cart" a button on mini cart

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I'm trying to make the "view and edit cart" link at the bottom of the mini cart a button.

[image: Magento 2.1.10 MiniCart View and Edit Cart Link]

I have copied content.html to my child theme

> app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Mytheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Within **content.html** the "**View and edit cart**" link is generated from

```
    <div class="actions">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View and Edit Cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have changed it to

```
    <div class="actions">
       <div class="secondary">
                 <button
                    id="lower-cart-btn-checkout"
                    type="button"
                    class="action viewcart"
                    data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <!-- ko i18n: 'View and Edit Cart' --><!-- /ko -->
            </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button is generated. However, when you click the button nothing happens.
[image: Magento 2.1.10 MiniCart View and Edit Cart Button]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always be `<a>` tag (link). Add whatever class you want and convert that link into Button using **CSS**

`data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}"` attribute will NOT work with `<button>` Tag

```
<!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
<div class="actions">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a id="minicart-to-editcart" class="button action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="secondary">
     <a class="action btn btn-default btn-full margin-bottom15" href="https://www.testdomain.com/en/categories">      
     <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Continue Shopping' --><!-- /ko --></span>
     </a>
</div>
```

I have a Category page https://www.testdomain.com/categories.

How can i get this in attribute format in minicart html.

The Above Link not working.I have english and arabic Store.

Thanks